# Dynamically update the slide table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have google slide which has table, that i want to update from sheet, so that If new data get added in sheet it should increase the rows in table of slide, or it delete the rows in slide based on number of rows in sheet. And if rows in sheet data is more suppose only 10 rows can get into one slide, script should also add new slide with remaining data(if possible)

I am new to slide, I created the function to get the data from sheet based on condition which I need but I am facing issue(because of limited knowledge about slide) to update the table of slide based on condition mentioned above.

Code I am using now :-

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheets = ['Sheet1']


function getData() {

        sheets.forEach(r=>{
        let ssname = ss.getSheetByName(r)
        let [head,...data] = ssname.getDataRange().getValues()
        let pos_Lead = head.indexOf('Customer Success Leader')
        let leaders = [...new Set(data.map(function(a){return a.slice(pos_Lead,pos_Lead+1)}).flat())].filter(r=> r)
          for(let i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) /// leader.length
          {
              let thisLeadData = data.filter(r=> r[pos_Lead] === leaders[i])
              let slide = SlidesApp.openById('12yIyuo6MSbKriYQ_wZ9Kol6ctLzB5Vnpu49zwy-w-aQ')
              let wellNess = slide.getSlideById('p1')
              let table = wellNess.getTables()[0]
              let row = table.getCell(0)
          }
        })
}
```

Slide sample : https://docs.google.com/presentation/d//edit#slide=id.p1

Sheet Sample : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mu1W_DsMChfjwok5_gvDKkgMms_76YcTRLdLmk3nerk/edit#gid=1146242024

Code is behind the sheet.

Thanks

Comment: The slide sample is not shared publicly, I can't access. Also, whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: How do you intend to handle the table being split to multiple slides, "add new slide with remaining data"?  I'm pretty sure that will become a new table.  When you talk about adding rows and deleting rows if the table is split into multiple slides which table do you add to and delete from?